# How to pass argument to a for loop from a file and run in parallel, and create log for each argument

Tags: linux, arguments, for, ansible

```bsh
for test in "${a[@]}"
do
    
    sh ansiblescript.sh -s $a

    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
        echo "Success"
    else
        echo "Failed"
        exit 1
    fi
done
```

I have the above for loop and it accepts input from the below file like

test.txt

```
a b c d
```

Right now it first runs for `a` and then goes to `b`. I want to run all four in parallel and write separate logs file for each one.

Comment: How is the file `test.txt` and its contents related to the loop you show, and why are you not using the `test` variable that you seem to be iterating with.  Also, what is the array `a` in your code and are you intentionally using its first element in the call to `ansiblescript.sh`, or is that a typo? What do you want to write to the log files (`Success` and `Failed`, or the output of the script?) and how should a failure be handled (you're currently using `exit 1` to break out of the loop and terminate the script)?

Answer (score 1):

For example, given the script for testing

```bsh
shell> cat ansiblescript.sh
timestamp=`date +"%b %d %H:%M:%S"`
printf "$timestamp ansiblescript.sh: started\n"
sleep 5
timestamp=`date +"%b %d %H:%M:%S"`
printf "$timestamp ansiblescript.sh: finished\n"
exit 0
```

The playbook below will create the directory */tmp/ansible* for the logs. Then, the content of the file *test.txt* will be split and iterated. The script will be executed asynchronously. See [Asynchronous actions and polling](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_async.html#asynchronous-actions-and-polling).

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - file:
        state: directory
        path: /tmp/ansible

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ '%b %d %H:%M:%S'|strftime }} Sctipts started."

    - shell:
        cmd: "sh ansiblescript.sh -s {{ item }} >>
              /tmp/ansible/ansiblescript-{{ item }}.log"
      register: result
      async: 30
      poll: 0
      loop: "{{ lookup('file', 'test.txt')|split(' ') }}"

    - async_status:
        jid: "{{ item.ansible_job_id }}"
      loop: "{{ result.results }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.item }} job_id={{ item.ansible_job_id }}"
      register: ap_result
      until: ap_result.finished
      retries: 30

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ '%b %d %H:%M:%S'|strftime }} Scripts finished."

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ (item.rc == 0)|ternary('Success', 'Failed') }}
              {{ item.start }}
              {{ item.end }}"
      loop: "{{ ap_result.results }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.item.item }}"
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml

PLAY [localhost] ***********************************************************

TASK [file] ****************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ***************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: Apr 13 22:35:23 Sctipts started.

TASK [shell] ***************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=a)
changed: [localhost] => (item=b)
changed: [localhost] => (item=c)
changed: [localhost] => (item=d)

TASK [async_status] ********************************************************
FAILED - RETRYING: [localhost]: async_status (30 retries left).
changed: [localhost] => (item=a job_id=881555332548.1994349)
changed: [localhost] => (item=b job_id=644490646974.1994376)
changed: [localhost] => (item=c job_id=859370052106.1994407)
changed: [localhost] => (item=d job_id=704644892779.1994438)

TASK [debug] ***************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: Apr 13 22:35:31 Scripts finished.

TASK [debug] ***************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=a) => 
  msg: Success 2022-04-13 22:35:24.569468 2022-04-13 22:35:29.581256
ok: [localhost] => (item=b) => 
  msg: Success 2022-04-13 22:35:24.846117 2022-04-13 22:35:29.858153
ok: [localhost] => (item=c) => 
  msg: Success 2022-04-13 22:35:25.112447 2022-04-13 22:35:30.127829
ok: [localhost] => (item=d) => 
  msg: Success 2022-04-13 22:35:25.393390 2022-04-13 22:35:30.405189
PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************
localhost: ok=6 changed=2 unreachable=0 failed=0 skipped=0 rescued=0 ignored=0
```

See the log files

```bsh
shell> cat /tmp/ansible/ansiblescript-a.log 
Apr 13 22:35:24 ansiblescript.sh: started
Apr 13 22:35:29 ansiblescript.sh: finished
```

```bsh
shell> cat /tmp/ansible/ansiblescript-b.log 
Apr 13 22:35:24 ansiblescript.sh: started
Apr 13 22:35:29 ansiblescript.sh: finished
```

```bsh
shell> cat /tmp/ansible/ansiblescript-c.log 
Apr 13 22:35:25 ansiblescript.sh: started
Apr 13 22:35:30 ansiblescript.sh: finished
```

```bsh
shell> cat /tmp/ansible/ansiblescript-d.log 
Apr 13 22:35:25 ansiblescript.sh: started
Apr 13 22:35:30 ansiblescript.sh: finished
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `&` and run a process in the background as in this
answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3643961/1572593

`sh ansiblescript.sh -s $a &`

You may have add logic to deal with the hangup signal. In other words what happens when your script ends and processes are still running. Research `wait` in this context as well as `nohup`.

Comment: Note that this affects the `if` statement after the `sh` and that the issue also contained a question about creating separate log files.

Comment: @akansha I can see  adding the sh command and the if else statement into a function. Then running that function in the background for each iteration with `&`. Question on logging are you only logging  the output to stdout of if/else? "Success" of "Failed"? Or are you attempting to log stdout/stderr of sh command as well?

Answer (score 0):

With GNU Parallel it looks like this:

```
parallel -j0 --result {}.out --joblog my.log sh ansiblescript.sh -s {} ::: "${a[@]}" || echo one or more failed
```